# Different keys for AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am looking for playing a remote mp4 video on tvOS with `AVPlayer`. (I am already successful in playing the video but there is one confusion) I have looked different forums and there is one method that i can use with AVURLAsset and the method is

```
 func loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(_ keys: [String],
                   completionHandler handler: (() -> Void)?)
```

I have seen people are using `playable, duration and tracks` as keys. I don't know what these keys do. My question is that where i can check documentation for the different keys for this function.

Also i don't understand what this line means in apple documentation

```
A “key” is any property in a class that implements this protocol.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading/loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:

Answer (score 1):

`AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading` is a protocol implemented by a number of classes, including `AVURLAsset` which is what you are using. Therefore, you can check the documentation for [`AVURLAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVURLAsset) (and its parent class, [`AVAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAsset)), where you will find the function of [`playable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/playable), [`tracks`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/tracks), [`duration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/duration) and other keys.